# How can I see only the database I have access to in pgAdmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, database, pgadmin, heroku

I created a free postgres database on Heroku, when connecting it to my pgAdmin4 the connection is done normally, however, thousands of databases appear along with mine. All the databases that appear I don't have access, only 1 that I have access (mine). see the image:
[image]

### See that many databases appear out of nowhere, but what I need is just this one, mine:

[image]

## Question:

#### 1. Is there any way to show just the database I have access to?

Comment: If those databases do not belong to you (or the Heroku account holder), then I would file a bug with Heroku as this would be an excellent way to reduce the amount of effort required to gain access to a database I don't have any business knowing about ... 

Answer (score 2):

You probably cannot set pgAdmin4 to see only databases which you have access to, but there is a workaround - you can set it to see only *selected* databases.

Right button on your server, select `Properties`, tab `Advanced`, and add the names of the databases you want to see in the `DB restriction` field. If the field contains data, the other databases disappear from the list.

Warning: once the connection is saved, the field becomes read-only :(

[image]

See also https://medium.com/@vapurrmaid/getting-started-with-heroku-postgres-and-pgadmin-run-on-part-2-90d9499ed8fb